# Dealing with magento templates

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I want to insert my `custom .phtml` code in one of the magento core page. To be more specific i want to put my code in order to be displayed in `<my-server-name>/index.php/admin/sales_order/view/order_id/1` page. For the sake of example i put the code direct into the `/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/view/tab/info.phtml` and now the view looks like in the capture.[image]

My question is how to achive this task but without touching the core file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the adminhtml templates. First add the admin theme in the stores -> admin section of your modules `config.xml`

```
<stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <theme>
                <template>yourcustomname</template>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

Then copy the original file to `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourcustomname/template/sales/view/tab/info.phtml` and make your changes.

But I think you missed something in the path, the original template is located in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`, therefore the custom template location would be `app/design/adminhtml/default/yourcustomname/template/sales/order/view/tab/info.phtml`

Comment: It works. Now, how can i inject some data from my controller in this template ? I want to display some data based on some logic created in my controller file.

Comment: I'm not sure what your controller's role is in this issue. Usually in Magento there are blocks which prepare the data for templates. In your case  the Magento block is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_Info`. You can overwrite that block and add whatever functionality there. The controller of that page is `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController` you may overwrite that too, depending on what you need to do and add functionality there. Depending on what you want to do you can also create a helper and simply get access it's methods from everywhere with `Mage::helper('yourhelpername')`

Answer (score 0):

But what if I want to override a file from front-end ? 
I need to override base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml file.

I try with this code in my .conf.xml file

```
<frontend>
    <design>
        <theme>
            <template>mycustomname</template>
        </theme>
    </design>
</frontend>
```

And I create new folder mycustomname and put it inside app/design/frontend/base/mycustomname